# Using MVC Razor functionality in .NET Framework 4.8

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

We have a large application targeting Framework 4.8 which uses the RazorEngine library to generate HTML-formatted emails.  Due to the fact this library has a vulnerability and is no longer maintained, I am trying to find an alternate implementation.  The RazorEngineCore package is too limited in its functionality; RazorLight looks good but I found a lot of errors that I was not able to resolve.

So I am trying an implementation using the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor library and the [RazorViewToStringRenderer](https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/blob/master/samples/Mvc.RenderViewToString/RazorViewToStringRenderer.cs) class from Github which seems to be frequently recommended.  My test concept application is throwing an error:

> "Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.CookieTempDataProvider'."

My sample:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection();
            services.AddMvcCore().AddRazorViewEngine();
            services.AddSingleton<RazorViewToStringRenderer>();

            var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            var service = provider.GetRequiredService<RazorViewToStringRenderer>();
        }
```

The error is thrown on the last line.

The only sample code I could find online was written for .NET Core so I had to modify it, since some of the method calls aren't available to me.  I am supposed to find a solution that will work while still targeting .NET Framework.  Can someone point out if I am doing something wrong?